# Can I choose parentheses or square brackets from a different font?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, typography

I'm using xelatex, and the font I use has absolutely horrific square brackets (KerkisSans - the left square bracket is smaller than the right and also none of them is square!). I want to change them with brackets from some other font. How can I do that?

Keep in mind that I need text mode, so something like redefining `\lbrack`, `\rbrack` won't work.

[Edit] MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{KerkisSans}

\begin{document}
[aren't these brackets horrible?] 

[also was this MWE \emph{that much} needed?]    
\end{document}
```

[/Edit]

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide small but complete document by which we can reproduce your brackets ...

Comment: done that. What's the need for such simple MWE?

Comment: (i) for people (like me), who like to see your brackets, is simple to test mwe (ii) bracket are (deliberately) design for this font ... (iii) your quesation is duplicate, but i haven't time now to search for it.